# tkinter program freezing when downloading file via mulithreading

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, progress-bar

I'm writing a program to download a url file but when using a thread for download and a thread for updating progress bar, program starts freezing. Onitially, when I made a thread for downloading, it worked good. However, I need to also update a progress bar in another thread, but then the code don't work correctly.

Thread for download:

```
t = threading.Thread(target=Handler,
        kwargs={'start': start, 'end': end, 'url': link, 'filename': file_name})
```

And thread for updating progress bar:

```
tu = threading.Thread(target=update, args=(end,))
tu.start().
```

Full code:

```
import os
import threading
import requests
from tkinter import filedialog
import  time
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

from tkinter import ttk
root=Tk()
root.title("DownloadManager")
size=0

def Export_File(): # PATH FOR PUT  FILE
    dir_name = filedialog.askdirectory() # asks user to choose a directory
    os. chdir(dir_name) # changes your current directory
    curr_directory = os.getcwd()
    s1=r"C:\Users\or30n\PycharmProjects\pythonProject"
    with open(s1+"\path.txt","w") as file:
        file.write(curr_directory)
    try:
        os.mkdir(curr_directory+"/downloadmanager")
        print(curr_directory)
    except:
        pass

button=ttk.Button(root,text="select path to save files...",command=Export_File)
button.pack()

url=StringVar()
btn_url=ttk.Entry(root,width="100",textvariable=url)
btn_url.pack()

def update(end):
    pv=pb_var.get() +(end *100) / s
    print(pv)
    pb_var.set(pv)
    #progress.update_idletasks()

#...............................
def Handler(start, end, url, filename):

    start=int(start)
    # specify the starting and ending of the file
    headers = {'Range': 'bytes=%d-%d' % (start, end)}

    # request the specified part and get into variable
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, stream=True)

    # open the file and write the content of the html page
    # into file.
    with open(filename, "r+b") as fp:
        fp.seek(start)
        var = fp.tell()
        fp.write(r.content)
    time.sleep(0.2)
def main_handler():
    respons = requests.get(url.get(), stream=True)
    start_time=time.time()
    filename = url.get().split('/')[-1]
    link = url.get()
    number_of_threads=3
    part = int(s) / number_of_threads

    with open("path.txt") as file:# PATH.TXT IS A FILE IN MAIN PROGRAM TO SAVE PATH FOR DOWNLOAD FILE
            cu = file.read()
    file_name=cu + "/downloadmanager" + "/" + filename
    f = open(file_name, "wb")
    f.seek(s)
    f.write(b"\0")
    f.close()


    for i in range(number_of_threads):
        start = part * i
        end = start + part


        # create a Thread with start and end locations
        t = threading.Thread(target=Handler,
                kwargs={'start': start, 'end': end, 'url': link, 'filename': file_name})
        t.setDaemon(True)
        t.start()

        tu = threading.Thread(target=update, args=(end,)) # THREAD FOR UPDATING PROGRESSBAR
        tu.start()


        main_thread = threading.current_thread()
        for t in threading.enumerate():
            if t is main_thread:
                continue
            t.join()

#------------------------------------------------------------

def showsearch():
    btn_search = ttk.Button(root, text="Start Download",command=main_handler)
    btn_search.pack()

def check_url():
    if(btn_url.get()!=''):
        print(url.get().split('/')[-1])
        btn_ok.pack_forget()
        responshead = requests.head(url.get(), stream=True)
        print(responshead.headers)
        btn_ok.config(command=showsearch())
        global s
        s=int(responshead.headers['Content-Length'])# LENGTH OF URL FILE
        str_siz=StringVar()
        str_siz=str(s//1000)+"KB"
        lb_size=ttk.Label(root,text=str_siz)
        lb_size.pack()
    else:
        messag=messagebox.showerror(title="Empty Url",message="please enter a url...")


btn_ok=ttk.Button(root,text="ok",command=check_url)
btn_ok.pack()
pb_var=IntVar()
pb_var.set(0)
progress = ttk.Progressbar(root, mode="determinate", maximum=100, length=300,variable=pb_var)
progress.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Delete `t.join()`.

Comment: You should remove the for loop that executes `join()` which will block the application until the thread task completes.